# How to make android device vibrate when an on-screen number changes

Tags: java, android

I'm very new to programming and I'm making my first android app.
I was wondering if there is a way to make the android phone vibrate when a number on the screen (used for keeping a count) reaches a certain value.
Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks!

```
 ...
  buttonplus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override public void onClick(View v) {
        counter1++; 
        maincount.setText(Integer.toString(counter1));
        counter2--;
        cardsremain.setText(Integer.toString(counter2));
        counter3 = (counter1 * 10 / counter2);
        truecount.setText(Integer.toString(counter3));
```

I wish to vibrate the phone when the 3rd counter is a positive number

Comment: can you post the code which you are using to set number

Comment: buttonplus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter1++;
                maincount.setText(Integer.toString(counter1));
                counter2--;
                cardsremain.setText(Integer.toString(counter2));
                counter3 = (counter1 * 10 / counter2);
                truecount.setText(Integer.toString(counter3));

I wish to vibrate the phone when the 3rd counter is a positive number

Comment: Try to explain your situation more clearly, code you have written, if it doesn't work then why and things you have tried so far.

Comment: The code I have provided is for a basic counting app.
One number counts positively while one number counts negatively from a set value.
A third number counts based on a mathematical division of the first and second number.
I wish to have the device vibrate when the third number changes to a positive number.
I have not tried anything so far as I'm not sure how to achieve this.